# Cannot autocomplete other textfields using CJuiAutoComplete

Tags: php, autocomplete, yii2, yii-extensions

I have a model that has fields `id_peg`, `nama_peg`, and `jabatan_peg`. So here's what I wanna do:

1. Autosuggestion that shows the list of`id_peg` as I type in the text field `id_peg`
2. When I select the suggested `id_peg`, the fields `nama_peg` and `jabatan_peg` are autocompleted based on that corresponding selected value (retrieved from database)

I've been trying to do the first one and I did it. But I'm stuck at the second one.

This is what I did:

view/melaporkan.php:

```
              $this->widget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiAutoComplete', array(
                    'name' => 'test1',
                    'source' => $this->createUrl('search'),
                    // additional javascript options for the autocomplete plugin
                    'options' => array(
                        'showAnim' => 'fold',
                        'select' => 'js:function(event, ui) {  
                              $('#nama_peg').val(ui.item.nama_peg);
                              $('#jabatan_peg').val(ui.item.jabatan_peg); 
                        }',
                    ),                            
                ));
```

controllers/sitecontroller.php

```
public function actionSearch() {
    $res = array(0 => array('id' => 1, 'value' => "id_peg"), 1 => array('id' => 2, 'value' => "jabatan_peg"), 2 => array('id' => 2, 'value' => "nama_peg"));
    if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
        $qtxt = "SELECT id_peg FROM pegawai WHERE id_peg LIKE :id_peg";
        $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($qtxt);
        $command->bindValue(":id_peg", '%' . $_GET['term'] . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $res = $command->queryColumn();

    }
    echo CJSON::encode($res);
    Yii::app()->end();
}
```

All it did was autosuggest for `id_peg`. When clicked some random `id_peg`, `nama_peg` and `jabatan_peg` were still empty.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is controllers/sitecontroller.php page.
You are sending only id_peg as JSON format but trying to get as ui.item.jabatan_peg.

It is always better to send your value as 
[{"id":"Caprimulgus europaeus","value":"European Nightjar"}] pattern
and get the value ui.item.value at your select function.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this: [{"id":"Caprimulgus europaeus","value":"European Nightjar"}]. Can you elaborate?

Comment: echo CJSON::encode($res);
this code is producing a JSON format something like 
[{"value1","value2"}]
but you want to access ui.item.jabatan_peg


try to first create a array

array(
   0=>array(
         'id' = 1,
          'value'=> "value1"
      ),
  1=>array(
         'id' = 2,
          'value'=> "value2"
      ),
)

then $('#jabatan_peg').val(ui.item.value); 
you will get your satisfactory result

Comment: I've updated the post. I did what you told me. It still doesn't work. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Update your ajax page

public function actionSearch() {
    $res = array();
    if (isset($_GET['term'])) {
        $qtxt = "SELECT id_peg FROM pegawai WHERE id_peg LIKE :id_peg";
        $command = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($qtxt);
        $command->bindValue(":id_peg", '%' . $_GET['term'] . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $res = $command->queryColumn();

    }
    $i =0;
    foreach($res as $model) {
               $i++;
               $suggest[] = array(
               'label'=> $i
               'jabatan_peg'=>$model,
    )

    echo CJSON::encode($suggest);
    Yii::app()->end();
}